# how to fetch parent table field value using queryset object in django template

Tags: django

I have below models -

Parent table -

```
class RoomCategory(models.Model):
    trust = models.ForeignKey(Trust, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    *category = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)*
    rate = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    num_guests = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_bedrooms = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_beds = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_toilets = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

child table1 having above room category pics as below

```
class RoomCategoryAttribute(models.Model):
    trust = models.ForeignKey(Trust, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    *image=models.ImageField(upload_to="room_cat_imgs/",null=True)*
```

child table2 having booking details

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    trust = models.ForeignKey(Trust, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True,blank=True, null=True)
    *category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)*
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    num_days = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    
    total_cost = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    when_booked = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

I have a below queryset in my views.py -

```
booking = Booking.objects.all()
```

In my template I am iterating over the above booking query set to show the bookings in cards as below

{% for booking in booking_list %}

Now the question is - in the cards - how do I show the first image from the child table1 i.e. RoomCategoryAttribute which has multiple rows of several images per RoomCategory - as I think there is some way to use ***_set.first.image and I tried with multiple ways but nothing works -

```
<div class="card-img-top overflow-hidden"><a href="user-booking-detail.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="/media/{{booking.category.category.roomcategoryattribute_set.first.image}}" alt="Modern, Well-Appointed Room"/></a></div>
```

Comment: {{ booking.category.roomcategoryattribute_set.first.image.url }}

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for reply but No this is not working as I tried just now....

Comment: best thing to do is test in your view after the line `booking = Booking.objects.all()` put `print(booking.first().category.roomcategoryattribute_set.first().image.url)` and see what you get

Comment: Hi Jimmy - got below error in console and in 
    print(booking.first().category.roomcategoryattribute_set.first().image.url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: also on the screen - Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: my bad - I got it in the print cmd and got the issue, some of the photos are not uploaded hence issue I believe, lets see - /media/room_cat_imgs/DSC_1706.jpg